# android Fragment issue with orientation change

Tags: android, fragment, android-orientation

I have activity and two layouts for it defined:

1. layout-large-land
2. layout

1st layout is for large screens in landscape mode, 2nd is for other cases. 
The 1st layout contains:

1. fragment1
2. fragment2

The 2nd layout contains:

1. fragment1

When I start the app in landscape mode on large screen, the `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` called in `Activity.onCreate()` correctly returns both fragments. After orientation change to portrait, `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` returns not null for `fragment2`, but it should return `null` because this fragment is not defined in this layout. The problem is that the returned fragment object is incorrect and I get `null` pointer exceptions while accessing it. It should be `null`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually... I don't think it should be `null`.

After your `layout-large-land` layout is displayed in the `Activity`, the `Activity` will add those both `Fragments` in the `FragmentManager`. Once you rotate your `Activity`, the `FragmentManager` retains it's state, and the `Fragments` inside it, and it still has that `Fragment2` in it, and that is why `findFragmentById()` does not return `null`.

The `Fragment2` will be there, but it won't be attached to the `Activity`, and you can check this by using `fragment.isAdded()` or `fragment.isVisible()`.

If in your case, you want to know if your 2-pane (landscape) or 1-pane(portrait), maybe you should do the following check : `findViewById(R.id.secondFragmentContainer)==null`.

Comment: Let's say you have 1 button on fragment1 and activity is displaying with portrait layout. you want to open fragment2 being its clicked. after it's clicked fragment2 is opened everything is ok so far, my problem starts here, when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape fragment1 is no visible. How could I provide that fragment1 and fragment2 should stand together even though I change the orientation?